# Matlab: How to do `repelem` where each element is a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, repeat, tensor

Suppose I have m-by-n matrices A, B, C arranged in an m-by-n-by-3 tensor P:

```
P = cat(3, A, B, C);
```

I now want to make a new tensor where each matrix is repeated K times, making the third dimension size 3K. That is, if K=2 then I want to build the tensor

```
Q = cat(3, A, A, B, B, C, C);
```

Is there a nice builtin way to achieve this, or do I need to write a loop for it? Preferably as fast or faster than the manual way.

If A, B, C were scalars I could have used `repelem`, but it does not work the way I want for matrices. `repmat` can be used to build

```
cat(3, A, B, C, A, B, C)
```

but that is not what I am after either.

Comment: `P = [A, B, C]` is not an m-by-n-by-3 tensor, though. That would be `P = cat(3, A, B, C)`.

Comment: Once you've got the tensor in the proper shape, `repmat` will work as expected.

Comment: I'm using the notation loosely to get the idea across. In proper matlab notation it would be `P(:,:,1) = A`, `P(:,:,1) = B`, `P(:,:,1) = C`, and similarly for the other examples.

Comment: How do you mean I should use `repmap`? If I do `repmat(P, 1, 1, K);` I get the wrong thing, as explained in the question.

Comment: It does not get the idea across.

Comment: Okay, I can update the notation of the question.

Comment: Ah, I see now...

Comment: Hmm, I think I solved it. I can write `Q = P(:,:,repelem(1:3, 1, 2))`.

Comment: I think you should be able to use `repelem` directly on the 3D array? Something like `repelem(P,1,1,k)`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It works in Octave, not sure if it works in MATLAB.

Comment: I was convinced that I had tried that, and that it didn't work, but lo and behold, seems like it does! And I can see now also why it should work. Thank you!

Comment: LOL... I guess I'll modify my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75120107/matlab-how-to-do-repelem-where-each-element-is-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment132563049_75120107) by [@Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo), `repelem(P, 1, 1, k)` will actually do what you want (in spite of what the MATLAB documentation says), but I can think of two other ways to achieve this.

First, you could use `repmat` to duplicate the tensor `k` times in the **second** dimension and then reshape:

```matlab
Q = reshape(repmat(P, 1, k, 1), m, n, []);
```

Second, you could use `repelem` to give you the indices of the third dimension to construct `Q` from:

```matlab
Q = P(:, :, repelem(1:size(P,3), k));
```

Comment: Haha, I just realized I myself that I can use the second method. Thank you for both suggestions!

Comment: If Matlab is smart enough to do it with just pointer management under the hood this should also be very efficient.

Comment: And don't forget good old indexing: `Q = P(:, :, ceil(1/K:1/K:end))`